# How to get two a tags inline inside an li tag that is inside a nav-tab that is nav-justified

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

I have some `nav-tabs` and I am trying to insert two `a` tags inside one of the `li` tags that is one of the tabs.  The issue I am having is that the `a` tag appear on different lines.  I have tried to inline the `a` tags but that does not seem to work.  What should I do so both `a` tags are on the same line?

Here is a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/aaronmk2/DTcHh/51099/

Here is my Html code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified" role="tablist">
                <li role="presentation" class="active test">
                    <a href="#" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" class="test1">View</a>
                     <a href="" class="test1"><i class="fa fa-question-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my css

```
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');

body {
    margin: 10px;
}
.test{
  display: inline;
}
.test1{
  display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably wrap the 2 a tags in a span tag and add an inline for that as well.

```
span{
  display: inline;
}
```

See Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/51103/

Answer (score 0):

Since you want two `<a>`s, you will have to override default Bootstrap styles for the nav. So something like this will work:

```
ul > li > .test1 { 
  display: inline;
}
```

Bootstrap is selecting via `ul > li > a` so you just want to make it more specific. You can also do this:

```
.test1 {
  display: inline !important;
}
```